# How to create a hello world cloud computing application in c/c++

Tags: c++, cloud

Anyone knows of such a simpliest hello world app ?

Comment: hello world cloud computing.. wtf are you smoking?

Comment: Don't feel weird for the comments you gained. I'm looking for "cloud" deployment of C++ code as well, and instead of being so overwhelmed by the question, these people should have reasoned why C++ and "cloud" would be an awkward mix.

Comment: At least Amazon EC2 runs on full virtual machine images, making C++ very usable. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide

Answer (score 0):

http://www.zircomp.com/sites/default/files/doxygen/znet_5.0/group__js__tutorial.html

Here is precisely "hello world' for distributed computing, the idea behind this tutorial is to concentrate on simplicity and uniformity of multi- and distributed-core programming. Cloud is just another hardware offering and as long as your application could become elastic it'll fit cloud just fine.